# How to run feature specs only on master branch in CircleCI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, circleci

I would like to setup my CircleCI builds to only run feature specs on builds of the master branch.

Here is how I am attempting to accomplish this:

```
test:
  override:
    - case $CIRCLE_BRANCH in master) bundle exec rspec ;; *) bundle exec rspec --exclude-pattern "spec/features/**/*_spec.rb" ;; esac:
        parallel: true
```

This does seem to work, but my specs run much slower than they do using CircleCI's built in 'rspec parallel' feature - defeating the purpose of removing feature specs from most builds.

Is there a better way to achieve the same thing?